# SQL query combined column values

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm really not sure how to title this question... Imagine that we have a table looking like this:

```
object | attribute | value
------------------------------
   7     country     Germany
   7     position    12
   7     points      12
   8     country     Germany
   8     position    10
   8     points      3
```

Now I want to select all object identifiers that has country germany and position 12 or 5

I have no idea how to write this query, is it possible?

Comment: Vic, In my humble experience fifth normal form sucks in practice... You end up writing 10 times the code to do the same job... so is there any chance you can denormalise that table back to competitor (id, country, position, points)? ... ergo: one table per type-of-object?

Comment: @corlettk: This is not 5th normal form, this is an EAV design.

Comment: I'm not allowed to change the table structure :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Join as many times as you need additional query options:

```
SELECT t1.object
FROM table t1
    INNER JOIN table t2 ON t1.object = t2.object
WHERE t1.attribute = 'country' AND t1.value = 'Germany'
    AND t2.attribute = 'position' AND t2.value IN (12,5)
```

Comment: There's a slight risk of record duplication, if `(object, attribute)` doesn't have a unique key with it

Comment: If this is a worry, replace the first line with `SELECT DISTINCT t1.object`

Comment: I'm not sure what I might be doing wrong but I get "Table 'projectx.t2' doesn't exist"

Answer (score 3):

You have to join the table with itself:

```
SELECT *
FROM foo l
JOIN foo r ON l.object=r.object AND r.attribute='position'
WHERE l.attribute='country' AND l.value='Germany' AND r.value IN (5,12)
```

Comment: There's a slight risk of record duplication, if `(object, attribute)` doesn't have a unique key with it